# Recording a video podcast at a certain time / using vlc or another program like a DVR / PVR

Tags: video, vlc, video-streaming

I have several video podcast I would like to record and watch them when I get home.  Is there a program that will allow me to record podcast at a certain time in vlc or some other video program.  I'm trying to setup some type of DVR video podcasting system instead of waiting a day to down load the edited version of the podcast.

Thanks 
PS I have ubuntu 13.04 linux 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using ubuntu 13.04 make sure you install the schedule task from the ubuntu software center.

[image]

Create 2 task:

**1st task:** start the recording at a specific time and the command to use is

```
/usr/bin/cvlc http://bglive-a.bitgravity.com/twit/live/high --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=22050}:std{access=file,mux=mkv,dst=/tmp/vdd.mkv}'
```

[image]

**2nd task:** kill the vlc process at a certain time.  (note if you have more than one instance of vlc running this may not work and use military time)

```
pkill vlc
```

[image]