# VLC PVR question

Tags: indicator, vlc

This is in regards to the link below:

[Recording a video podcast at a certain time / using vlc or another program like a DVR / PVR](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329852/recording-a-video-podcast-at-a-certain-time-using-vlc-or-another-program-like)

How do I insert the current date in the output file name?

Comment: Are you using that Scheduled Tasks application, or some other method?

Comment: I am trying to use the GNOME when command. Thank You.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/when ?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:franzg/when-command
sudo apt update   
sudo apt install when